# How to write a console-application with windows on a terminal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, console, prompt, curses

I want to write a simple chat-client in Ruby for the terminal.
The Problem is, that I need two separate "windows", one for the chatlog and another for the input prompt. I dont have a clue how to do this. I watched (n)curses and some other ruby-libs, but nothing gives me this functionality.

```
.------------------------------.
| Mike: Hi Jenny               |
| Jenny: Hi Mike, how are you? |
|------------------------------|
|> I am fine_                  |
`------------------------------'
```

The big Problem is, if a new Line arives, the upper frame should scroll, but the prompt should stay on its position. And if I write something in the input prompt, the text should disappear when the user press ENTER.

Comment: Which os(es) are you planning to run it on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, ncurses (and its ruby binding library) does allow you for this since all the corresponding tools with `windows(1)`, `talk(1)` and `screen(1)` are written with ncurses.  You can have multiple windows with (n)curses.

Comment: I can't find any information about how to use curses-lib from the ruby-stdlib :-(

Comment: If you install the ncurses gem, you have some examples in there.

Comment: just a note to mention that ncurses has yet to be ported to windows. For that you must use curses